why I use 1 form as view and insert becomes an error in the datagridview CellValidated event with vb.net
I'm Trying to use 1 form as view and insert but becomes an error the datagridview CellValidated event with vb.net when I do a click in column Productname .
can I disable the event when I use the form as a view ?
Is there anything wrong with my code ?
Please Guide me
Thanks
Code in invoicepage
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Dapper

Public Class invoicepage
    Dim InvoicesService As New InvoicesService()
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ' To reduce the flickering...
        DataGridView1.GetType().
    GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).
    SetValue(DataGridView1, True)
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        LoadData()
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewLinkColumn With {
.Name = "Colview",
.Text = "‍",
.HeaderText = "",
.DisplayIndex = 1,
.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = True,
.ActiveLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumAquamarine,
.LinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumAquamarine,
.VisitedLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumAquamarine,
.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.NeverUnderline,
.ReadOnly = True,
.DataPropertyName = "Colview"})
    End Sub
    Private Sub LoadData()
        Dim list = InvoicesService.GetInvoices()
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Invoices)(CType(InvoicesService.GetInvoices(), IList(Of Invoices)))}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource
        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
    End Sub
    Private Function GetSELECT() As Invoices
        Return If(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = 0, Nothing, TryCast(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).OwningRow.DataBoundItem, Invoices))
    End Function
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso
        dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("colview") Then
            Dim SelectDgv = GetSELECT()
            Dim frm = New Frm_Invoice(SelectDgv)
            If (TryCast(Application.OpenForms("Frm_Invoice"), Frm_Invoice)) IsNot Nothing Then
                'Form is already open
                MessageBox.Show("Form is already open")
            Else
                ' Form is not open
                'MessageBox.Show("Form is not open")
                frm.Show()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

code in form_invoice (transaction)
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Dapper

Public Class Frm_Invoice
    Inherits Form
    Private dictProducts As Dictionary(Of String, ProductFinaltesting)
    Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private BindingSource2 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Dim InvoicesService As New InvoicesService()
    Public Sub New(Invno As Invoices)
        Me.New
        ' To reduce the flickering...
        DataGridView1.GetType().
    GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).
    SetValue(DataGridView1, True)

        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of InvoicesDetail)(CType(InvoicesService.GetInvoicesdetail(Invno.INVNO), IList(Of InvoicesDetail)))}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        TextBox1.Text = Invno.INVNO
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' To reduce the flickering...
        DataGridView1.GetType().
    GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).
    SetValue(DataGridView1, True)
        updateDataSource()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

    End Sub
    Protected Sub updateDataSource()
        dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().
    ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p)
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)}
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("No").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prp").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prs").ReadOnly = True
        BindingSource1.AddNew()
        DataGridView1.Select()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidated(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
'Error below line code
  If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit Or p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp Or p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                    boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)

                End If

                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
                Btnsave.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class




Please read this and edit your question accordingly. For you, the important point is "minimal".

@jmcilhinney , thanks for reply
